# What Emacs Lisp boolean/logical convenience functions exist?

Tags: boolean

**What boolean/logical convenience functions / macros are available for Emacs Lisp in either the core set of functions or external packages?**

I'm interested in just about anything other than the built-in logical operators in `and`, `or`, `not` (`null`) and conditional forms (`if`, `when`, `unless`, `cond`).  To illustrate the sort of convenience functions I have in mind:

Common Lisp has sequence predicates such as **`some` and `every`** and other functions like **`count-if`** (in `cl-lib` as `cl-some`, `cl-every`, and `cl-count-if` respectively).  When used with an identity function, `(cl-some #'identity my-list)` it performs a logical OR over elements in the list and `(cl-every #'identity my-list)` performs a logical AND over elements in the list.  These are convenient and are nearly ideal, but aren't purely logical functions because they require a predicate that is applied to each element.  These functions are available in `cl-lib`.

**`and` and `or`** conceptually fill the same niche, but clearly note that their use is limited because they are implemented as macros.  Expressions such as `(apply #'and my-list)` are not possible.

I have reviewed the list of ~1089 built-in Elisp functions and macros and only know of two relevant convenience functions.  **`booleanp`** checks if the argument's value is `t` or `nil` and **`not`** is an alias for `null`.

There are also numerous **boolean vector convenience functions** that are a part of Elisp, but as far as I can tell are only suitable for binary manipulation.

@Dan points out the use of **`memq`** to search for nil values in a list can evaluate functions of logical values of a list using variations of `(memq nil my-list)`.

An example of a potential convenience function would be a boolean identity function that simply converts a value to its canonical boolean form.

```
(defun boolean-identity (x)
  (if x t nil))
```

Comment: Unclear; please try to specify what you want more clearly. What does "functions for processing boolean values" mean? In Lisp, every value is a Boolean value (every value is `nil` or non-`nil`). Processing how, to do what? Just what kind of values are in your "list of boolean values"?

Comment: That would be probably `(if x t nil)`. `(x)` would treat `x` as a function and call it.  I've only heard about purity in logic in the context of Prolog language, where there are logical and extra-/non- logical predicates. Is this what you mean when you say "purely logical functions"?

Comment: @wvxvw Nope; that was a typo :-\

Answer (score 12):

It's not 100% clear what you're looking to do.  As a general response, Emacs Lisp treats all non-`nil` values as true for logical testing purposes.

As such, just about the only "boolean" predicates, in the sense that you seem to be using the term, are `null` and `not`, which, as the [manual states](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List_002drelated-Predicates.html), are identical:

> This function returns `t` if object is `nil`, and returns `nil` otherwise. This function is identical to `not`, but as a matter of clarity we use `null` when object is considered a list and not when it is considered a truth value.

So:

```
(null nil)                              ; => t
(not nil)                               ; => t
(null t)                                ; => nil
(not t)                                 ; => nil
(null '(a b c))                         ; => nil
(null '())                              ; => t (empty list is nil)
```

If you're looking to see if some or all of the elements of a list are non-`nil`, you can use `memq`.  Here's an example of testing that each element is non-`nil`:

```
(memq nil '(a b c))                     ; => nil
(null (memq nil '(a b c)))              ; => t (so all elements are non-nil)
```

Here's an example showing that not all elements are non-`nil`:

```
(memq nil '(a b nil))                   ; => (nil)
(null (memq nil '(a b nil)))            ; => nil (so not all elements are non-nil)
```

Note that you can also use `or` and `and` to do implicit `nil` testing:

```
(and 1 2 3)                             ; => 3
(and 1 2 nil)                           ; => nil
(or 1 2 3)                              ; => 1
(or nil 2 3)                            ; => 2
(or nil nil nil)                        ; => nil
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the example code you provided, I am guessing you are looking for this:

```
(-non-nil my-list-of-boolean-values)
```

Of course `-non-nil` is from the `dash` library. If you don't want to use `dash`, then you might have to go with:

```
(cl-mapcan (lambda (elt) (and elt (list elt)))
           my-list-of-boolean-values)
```

Comment: I'm glad you made this observation.  I had not been familiar with dash as a  library of utility functions.  I presumed that it was an internal utility function of what I now what I now realize is the completely distinct package helm-dash (for the Dash documentation project).  Dash.el has a wealth of useful functions!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @tarsius's solution:

```el
(cl-remove-if-not #'identity (list 1 2 3 nil)) => '(1 2 3)
```